# Permittivity vs resistance of metals and skin depth

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric, metals

I'm asked to estimate the skin depth of copper at a certain frequency, but in deriving the equation for skin depth we basically need to assume $-\omega^2\varepsilon+j\omega\sigma\approx j\omega\sigma$, or essentially $|\omega\varepsilon|<<\sigma$. [This](http://www.bndhep.net/Lab/Derivations/Skin_Effect.html) basically just states it is true for copper but stating the value of $\sigma/\varepsilon$, but doesn't say how it got that value.

Is $\sigma/\varepsilon$ just a known quantity by itself? Whenever I google anything about this the answers are dominated by people repeating that $\varepsilon=\infty$ but clearly that doesn't work here...

Comment: I found something called dielectric spectroscopy that seem to measure permittivity.

Comment: We don't HAVE to assume this, you can easily solve for skindepth without this assumption

Comment: @jensenpaull It seems to me without this assumption you get that the skindepth is then a function of $\varepsilon$, which doesn't seem to be a very known value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lecture in my electrodynamics course cleared this up:

When people say $\varepsilon=\infty$ for a conductor, they are trying to get across that, in a static field, the resultant steady state solution is identical to if you had a material of infinite polarizability. Current flows to or from the boundary of your conductor, leaving static charge which eventually cancels the external field. But what happens in this picture if we have incident light, so $\vec{E}=\vec{E}_0e^{(i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-\omega t)}$? This will in general have a component parallel to the interface. You could say that charge builds up at the edges of the conductor which alters the incoming wave near the interface, and maybe at small enough $\omega$ something like that would happen, but the reality is that this picture just breaks down for an electric field which changes in time.

Thus for the picture at hand, of a conductor with dielectric constant $\varepsilon$ and conductivity $\sigma$ such that $\vec{J}=\sigma \vec{E}$, it makes more sense to think of $\varepsilon$ as associated with any remaining bound (i.e. localized to the ionic nuclei) electrons in the material, and thus a reasonably finite value. If you're explicitly told this material is a conductor then, it is perfectly reasonable to assume the $\sigma$ term dominates.

As for estimating $\sigma/\varepsilon$, to do this one needs a bit more information. It turns out that adding a conductivity $\sigma$ constraint to maxwell's equations is mathematically equivalent to letting $\varepsilon$ be imaginary (i.e. the complex permittivity), and have some frequency dependence, where the complex component is goes as something like $1/\omega$. For copper, for example, one could probably find the complex permittivity at optical frequencies, evaluate maxwell's equations to get the correspondence of the imaginary part with $\sigma$, and confirm that this term dominates.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, there is no practical way to measure permittivity of conductor in low frequency. So I often assume that $\epsilon=\epsilon_0$. The permittivity is insulator specific quantity, I believe it is hard to apply permittivity concept to conductors in low frequencies.

Comment: Is there any reference for permittivity of conductors at optical frequencies then? I'm quite curious where the page I linked got the value of $\sigma/\varepsilon$; I can't seem to find anything similar anywhere

Comment: I cannot answer this question due to my lack of knowledge. I think one example of the permittivity of conductor in optical frequency is the [Drude model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model), which is a theoretical inspect of conductivity and permittivity of metal in optical frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

For a 'good' conductor, skin depth (in Gaussian units)  is given by
\begin{equation}
\delta=\frac{1}{2\alpha}=\frac{c}{\sqrt{8\pi\mu\sigma\omega}},
\end{equation}
and does not depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: My question was about the derivation of this. The formula itself is easy to find.

Comment: The derivation is a bit long and involved, but it is in many EM textbooks.  All you have to know about $\epsilon$ is that it is not <<1.  I thought your question was about "the value of σ/ε".